# Resources ? Loading theme (resource dictionary) but 

Tags: wpf, resources, dictionary, themes

How can i do - ?

- Load a large `ResourceDictionary` with (or not) `MergedDictionaries`, but only add those keys which are not found in resources (Application.Current.Resources) and update which are found.

I want to do this as i have many themes for my wpf app, but some controls style are fixed. So i first clear all resources, then load new one (everything gets cleared up). There are many fixed style controls so i can't load each one's.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Found and not found where?  What really are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application.Resources is a ResourceDictionary.  The dictionary you load is also a ResourceDictionary.  You can add resources to a ResourceDictionary via Add.  You can enumerate the resources within a ResourceDictionary since it implements ICollection.  You can also query whether a resource exists since it implements IDictionary.  A ResourceDictionary can hold other ResourceDictionaries in its collection of ResourceDictionaries: MergedDictionaries.

How you want to merge these depends on a few things.  One tactic I've used is to merge at the ResourceDictionary level, so I remove a ResourceDictionary from my Application.Resources.MergedDictionaries, and then add the ResourceDictionary I loaded.  If you want to merge by adding single resources that exist in your ResourceDictionary, but to not exist yet in Application.Resources, you can enumerate like this:

```
void AddOrUpdate(DictionaryEntry resource)
{
    // If it exists, remove it; contains checks base and merged dictionaries
    if (Application.Current.Resources.Contains(resource.Key))
    {
        // Must try to remove from all; if it doesn't exist there is no effect
        Application.Current.Resources.Remove(resource.Key);
        foreach (ResourceDictionary nextDictionary in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
            nextDictionary.Remove(resource.Key);
    }

    // We can now add it
    Application.Current.Resources.Add(resource.Key, resource.Value);
}


void MergeMyDictionary(ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary)
{
    foreach (DictionaryEntry nextResource in myResourceDictionary)
        AddOrUpdate(nextResource);
    foreach (ResourceDictionary nextDictionary in myResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry nextResource in nextDictionary)
            AddOrUpdate(nextResource);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I created a control for changing themes, that hang outs, and works after 3-4 clicks on changing theme or removing focus from app. ???

Comment: Great that it works.  I notice ??? (and that you have not accepted the answer).  Is there still a question?

Comment: Yes. Why app hangs and works after 3-4 clicks on changing theme or removing focus from app. ???

Comment: If by "hangs and works" you mean the app seems to stall a bit, you may be loading a lot of resources and it may be taking time to sort through them.  If so, periodically call System.Windows.Forms.DoEvents() to keep the app somewhat responsive.